# How to stop execution when working queue is empty and all threads have stopped working?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

While writing a state-space search like algorithm, I have a working queue with node elements. I have multiple threads with access to that queue that pop an element, do some transformations and checks to it, and may add more nodes to be visited to the queue.

I want the program to stop whenever the queue is empty, and all threads have stopped working (since they could add more elements in which case we would need the other threads to help handling these new nodes).

How should I go about making that check? I was currently thinking keeping some `AtomicBitSet`, keeping track of which threads are working and which are not, and stop execution when the bitset is empty. I would set and unset with the following, in the `run` method of my handlers

```java
while (!bitset.isAllUnset()) {
    Node node = queue.poll();
    if (node == null) {
        bitset.unset(THREAD_INDEX);
    } else {
        bitset.set(THREAD_INDEX);

        // HANDLE THE NODE
    }
}
```

Is there any recommended method to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is the following approach:

1. Create a ThreadPool and push the initial Task to your Queue.
2. Keep one Thread (you main Thread) as a Monitor on the ThreadPool.
3. The job of this Thread is to start new Threads as long as the Queue is not empty, the Thread Pool still has capacity left and give them their Task.
4. A Thread that is started will do its job and writes the results back to the queue.
5. Afterwards it is returned to the pool and you will have to wake up your Monitor.
6. Your Main Thread will then try to start a new thread as long as the Thread Pool has not reached is limit and the Task Queue is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ExecutorService` to which you submit the `Runnable`s that read the queue and which stop running when the queue is empty.

Then call the executor service 's `awaitTermination()` method which will block until all threads are finished.

Or use `CompletableFuture`:

```
CompleteableFuture.allOf(
    CompleteableFuture.runAsync(
        () -> while(!queue.isEmpty()) handle(queue.poll())
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is actually rather complicated. I do not know how to write a correct version using a set based approach. For example, the following approach is wrong:

```
public class ThreadsStopWorkingWrong {
ConcurrentLinkedQueue queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
ConcurrentHashMap activeThreads = new ConcurrentHashMap();
volatile int prozessedCount = 0;
volatile boolean stop = false;
@Interleave(group = ThreadsStopWorkingWrong.class, threadCount = 1)
public void readFromQueue() {
    int prozessAdditionalElements = 1;
    while (!stop) {
        Object element = queue.poll();

        if (element != null) {
            activeThreads.put(Thread.currentThread(), "");
            if (prozessAdditionalElements > 0) {
                prozessAdditionalElements--;
                queue.offer("2");
            }
            prozessedCount++;
        } else {
            activeThreads.remove(Thread.currentThread());
        }
    }
}
@Interleave(group = ThreadsStopWorkingWrong.class, threadCount = 1)
public void waitTillProzessed() throws InterruptedException {
    while (!queue.isEmpty() && !activeThreads.isEmpty()) {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    }
    assertEquals(2, prozessedCount);
}
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    queue.offer("1");
    Thread worker = new Thread(() -> readFromQueue());
    worker.start();
    waitTillProzessed();
    worker.join();

}
}
```

The problem is that when you poll the message out of the queue you have not yet added the thread to the activated set so !queue.isEmpty() && !activeThreads.isEmpty() becomes true. What works is using a message counter as in the following example:

```
public class ThreadsStopWorkingCorrect {
ConcurrentLinkedQueue queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
AtomicLong messageCount = new AtomicLong();
volatile int prozessedCount = 0;
volatile boolean stop = false;
@Interleave(group = ThreadsStopWorkingCorrect.class, threadCount = 1)
public void readFromQueue() {
    int prozessAdditionalElements = 1;
    while (!stop) {
        Object element = queue.poll();
        if (element != null) {
            if (prozessAdditionalElements > 0) {
                prozessAdditionalElements--;
                queue.offer("2");
                messageCount.incrementAndGet();
            }
            prozessedCount++;
            messageCount.decrementAndGet();
        }
    }
}
@Interleave(group = ThreadsStopWorkingCorrect.class, threadCount = 1)
public void waitTillProzessed() throws InterruptedException {
    while (messageCount.get() > 0) {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    }
    assertEquals(2, prozessedCount);
}
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    queue.offer("1");
    messageCount.incrementAndGet();
    Thread worker = new Thread(() -> readFromQueue());
    worker.start();
    waitTillProzessed();
    worker.join();

}
}
```

I tested both the example with [vmlens](https://vmlens.com), a tool I wrote to test multithreaded software. Therefore the Interleave annotations.

In the set-based version, some thread interleavings lead to prozessedCount==0.
In the counter-based version, the prozessedCount is always 2.